# using multiple some in object and array of object failed in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I want to check where an object's array of object has is_new equal to true but my below code gave me `true` for every iteration.

https://jsfiddle.net/7rLwzno0/

```
    const groupedByMonthData = {
      "July": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:23:14",
          "date_from": "2017-07-18 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-07-18 23:59:59",
          "is_new": false
        }
      ],
      "August": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:24:34",
          "date_from": "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-08-09 23:59:59",
          "is_new": true
        }
      ]
    }

    let hasIsNew = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).some( month => 
       groupedByMonthData[month].some( obj => obj.is_new )   


)
```

I expect one false and one true, something is wrong with my code above.

Comment: @HassanImam what do you mean? July is false, August is true.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` ->
Return true if the callback function returns a truthy value for any array element; otherwise, false. So that mean in your case it will always return `true`.

Comment: You have just one "hasIsNew", which is true if some of the months are true (which is the case). What is the output you expect?

Comment: Try this `let hasIsNew = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => groupedByMonthData[month][0]["is_new"]);` ,

Comment: @JessieAnderson When I first saw the question it was `true` for both of month.

Comment: groupedByMonthData[month][0] <-- will this work? each month will have multiple array of objects

Comment: @JessieAnderson I thought you will get only one object. Sorry about the assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a new object where we have a property for every month with a boolean value indicating if it has some `true` value for `is_new` in the array, try the following:

```js
const groupedByMonthData = {
  "July": [
    {
      "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:23:14",
      "date_from": "2017-07-18 00:00:00",
      "date_to": "2017-07-18 23:59:59",
      "is_new": false
    }
  ],
  "August": [
    {
      "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:24:34",
      "date_from": "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
      "date_to": "2017-08-09 23:59:59",
      "is_new": true
    }
  ]
}

let hasIsNew = {};
Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).forEach(month => {
  hasIsNew[month] = groupedByMonthData[month].some((obj) => obj.is_new);
});
 
console.log(hasIsNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.some -> Return true if the callback function returns a truthy value for any array element; otherwise, false. So that mean in your case it will always return true.
If you want to get only the elements with `is_new` equal to `true`

```
 hasIsNewss = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => 
       groupedByMonthData[month].filter( obj => obj.is_new===true )   
)
.join(', '); // will make it a tring like -> 'false, true'
```

if you want array with booleans

```
hasIsNewss = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => 
   groupedByMonthData[month].some( obj => obj.is_new )   
)
```

Comment: it will return array [false, true], why not false and true?

Comment: I cant get what do you expect exactly!? if you want string `false, true` just add at the very end `.join(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const groupedByMonthData = {
      "July": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:23:14",
          "date_from": "2017-07-18 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-07-18 23:59:59",
          "is_new": false
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:23:14",
          "date_from": "2017-07-18 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-07-18 23:59:59",
          "is_new": false
        }
      ],
      "August": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:24:34",
          "date_from": "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-08-09 23:59:59",
          "is_new": true
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:24:34",
          "date_from": "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-08-09 23:59:59",
          "is_new": false
        }
      ]
    }


let hasIsNew = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => groupedByMonthData[month].some(o => o["is_new"]));
 console.log(hasIsNew);
 console.log(hasIsNew.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I expect one false and one true, something is wrong with my code above.

In fact `.some()` method will only return results if its callback returns `true` that's why, you will only get the case where it returns a truthy value, when it has `"isNew": true`.

That explains why you got only one result.

You should use `.map()` in the first call instead of `some`:

```
    let hasIsNew = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => 
       groupedByMonthData[month].some( obj => obj.is_new ) )
  console.log(hasIsNew);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const groupedByMonthData = {
      "July": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:23:14",
          "date_from": "2017-07-18 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-07-18 23:59:59",
          "is_new": false
        }
      ],
      "August": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-07-13 07:24:34",
          "date_from": "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
          "date_to": "2017-08-09 23:59:59",
          "is_new": true
        }
      ]
    }

    let hasIsNew = Object.keys(groupedByMonthData).map( month => 
       groupedByMonthData[month].some( obj => obj.is_new ) )
  console.log(hasIsNew.join("\n"));
```